# Find folders containing a file

Tags: find

How can I find all subfolders containing a given file?

For example, in a Minecraft server installation, the different worlds are stored in subfolders with arbitrary names. To identify that a given folder represents a world, I have to look for a `level.dat` inside it. Is there a command that finds all `level.dat` files and returns the folders that contain them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply find your file and return the dirname:

```
find -name 'level.dat' -exec dirname {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, find your files and extract the directory names in bulk:

> `find` *starting_directory* `–name level.dat –print | sed 's@/level.dat$@@'`

Answer (score 1):

Or implement your find yourself ;)

```
myfind(){ shopt -s nullglob; [[ -f $1 ]] && pwd; for i in */ ; do ( cd $i;myfind $1 ) done }
myfind level.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    find ~ -type f -name "level.dat" -printf '%h\n'
```

if there may be more then one file with this name, then pipe to `uniq`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to print only files that pass a certain test. I like this approach:

```
find . -type d -execdir test -f {}/level.dat \; -print
```

This finds all directories, that contains a file named `level.dat`.